# Replace element in vector based on first letter of character string

Tags: r, regex, replace

Consider the vectors below:

```
ID <- c("A1","B1","C1","A12","B2","C2","Av1")

names <- c("ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE","AVOCADO")
```

I want to replace the first character of each element in vector `ID` with vector `names` based on the first letter of vector `names`. I also want to add a `_0` **before each number between `0:9`**.

Note that the elements `Av1` and `AVOCADO` throw things off a bit, especially with the lowercase `v` in `Av1`.

The result should look like this:

```
res <- c("ALPHA_01","BRAVO_01","CHARLIE_01","ALPHA_12","BRAVO_02","CHARLIE_02", "AVOCADO_01")
```

I know it should be done with `regex` but I've been trying for 2 days now and haven't got anywhere.

Comment: *throw things off a bit* - actually, that is a very important bit. What is there is a `BINGO`  replacement for `Bi3`? And `BROTHER` for `Bro3`? Well, I mean it is not clear how you want to define the patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure what you mean? I want `A` to be replaced by `ALPHA` and `Av` by `AVOCADO`, as well as inserting a `_0`

Comment: Ok, but `ALPHA` starts with `A`, and `A1` and `Av1` start with `A`, how do you know there is `AVOCADO` to handle after that and that you need 2 first characters to use for a pattern?

Comment: I don't know, that''s why I'm asking more knowledgeable people than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn`.

```
library(gsubfn)
#remove the number part from 'ID' (using `sub`) and get the unique elements
nm1 <- unique(sub("\\d+", "", ID))
#using gsubfn, replace the non-numeric elements with the matching 
#key/value pair in the replacement
#finally format to add the "_" with sub
sub("(\\d+)$", "_0\\1", gsubfn("(\\D+)", as.list(setNames(names, nm1)), ID))
#[1] "ALPHA_01"   "BRAVO_01"   "CHARLIE_01" "ALPHA_02" 
#[5] "BRAVO_02"   "CHARLIE_02" "AVOCADO_01"
```

---

The `(\\d+)` indicates one or more numeric elements, and `(\\D+)` is one or more non-numeric elements.  We are wrapping it within the brackets to capture as a group and replace it with the backreference (`\\1` - as it is the first backreference for the captured group).

#### Update

If the condition would be to append 0 only to those 'ID's that have numbers less than 10, then we can do this with a second `gsubfn` and `sprintf`

```
gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf("_%02d", as.numeric(x)), 
                      gsubfn("(\\D+)", as.list(setNames(names, nm1)), ID))
#[1] "ALPHA_01"   "BRAVO_01"   "CHARLIE_01" "ALPHA_12" 
#[5]  "BRAVO_02"   "CHARLIE_02" "AVOCADO_01"
```

Comment: Thank you akrun - can you explain to me what each of the symbols mean within the `sub` and `gsubfn` functions actually mean? I can't make heads nor tails of it from the help files

Comment: @Bonono I added some explanation.  Please let me know if you have trouble

Comment: Yes, it makes sense - that's great! The help files just seem quite complicated to understand it clearly. How am I supposed to know when to put a `+` or a `$`?

Comment: @Bonono These are metacharacters `+` means one or more `*`  is zero or more (when you are not sure 100% that a number (`\\d*`) will be there, `$` represents the end of the string and `^` is the start of a string.

Comment: hey akrun, I've made a slight edit in the question to only add the `_0` when numbers are below 10. Is there a way of easily modifying the code for this?

Comment: @Bonono UPdated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this via base R, we can search for second character being `V` (as in AVOCADO) and substring 2 characters if that's true or 1 character if not. This will capture both AVOCADO and ALPHA. We then match those substrings with the letters extracted from ID (also convert `toupper` to capture Av with AV). Finally paste `_0` along with the number found in each `ID`

```
paste0(names[match(toupper(sub('\\d+', '', ID)), 
               ifelse(substr(names, 2, 2) == 'V', substr(names, 1, 2), 
                                substr(names, 1, 1)))],'_0', sub('\\D+', '', ID))
#[1] "ALPHA_01" "BRAVO_01" "CHARLIE_01" "ALPHA_02" "BRAVO_02" "CHARLIE_02" "AVOCADO_01"
```